# django project search bar

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to implement a search bar in my application
I use an API to retrieve product data then I search by code product,
But after searching it does not display the product found

Views.py

```
def search(request):
  code=request.GET.get('search')
  url='http://myAPI/Product/GetProducts'
  x=requests.post(url)
  content=x.json()
  all_products=content['products']
  selected_product= next((item for item in all_products if item['code']== code),None)
  if selected_product!= None:
    product=selected_product

  context={'product':product}
  return render(request,'cart/search.html',context)
```

search.html

```
<h3>Results:</h3>

{% for search in product %}
  {{search.code}}
  {{search.designation}}
{% endfor %}
```

And I noticed at the level of the url of my browser, that there is no value for action **(http://127.0.0.1:8000/cart/search/?search=or21&action=  )**

Here is the form

```
    <form method="GET" action="/cart/search/">
        <input type="search" name="search" placeholder="Exemple name product">
        <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light" type="submit">Search
        <i class="material-icons right">search</i>
      </button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, I just removed the loop and it displays the data now

```
  <h3>Results:</h3>
  {{search.code}}
  {{search.designation}}
```